# Using recv to receive incoming char array

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Am back with C sockets question.

I am trying to receive a char array from a client via TCP. I have the following *recv* code:

```
char buffer[2048];
int recvBytes = 0;

while (1) {

    if ((clntSockfd = accept(servSockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &clntSockAddrLen)) == -1) {
        printf("Unable to accept client connection\n");
    exit(1);
}
    else { 
        printf("Client connection accepted!\n");
    }

    /* clear buffer */
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    recvBytes = recv (clntSockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    printf("Bytes received: %i\n", recvBytes);
    printf("Char array received: %s\n", buffer);
}
```

I noted that upon execution, recvBytes shows zero in the first iteration. It's only after the second iteration that it picks up the incoming char array.

I would like to find out will recv block until I receive data from the incoming socket? How should I discard the unwanted chars in the buffer - i.e. drop the chars received from the first iteration.

Many thanks!

-- edit ---

Hi all, I have appended the console output from eclipse.

```
**... <- initialization stuff
Binding socket to port
Socket binded
Start listening on port 8081.
Client connection accepted!                  *while loop - first iteration
Bytes received: 0                            *while loop - first iteration
Char array received:                         *while loop - first iteration
Client connection accepted!                  *while loop - second iteration
Bytes received: 22                           *while loop - second iteration
Char array received: 1~Message~HowAreYou?    *while loop - second iteration**
```

Hope the above console output illustrates my questions clearer, regarding the first and second iterations. From the above, the first iteration is not receiving any bytes but recv does not block. I thought recv was supposed to block until it receives bytes?

Comment: recv does block until there are characters so there are no 'unwanted' chars in the buffer - whatever the value returned (recvBytes) is the number of chars in the buffer

Comment: @KevinDTimm: Unless `setsockopt` is used to put the socket into non-blocking mode.

Comment: If the OP would post more information, we could give better answers (IOW, the quality of the answer is equal to the quality of the question)

Comment: Hi KevinDTimm, Ben Voight, thanks for the heads up on recv. Also, I'm not running on non-blocking.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: If the socket is in non-blocking mode recv return -1 and errno == EAGAIN (Linux) or GetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK (Windows).

Comment: Hey KevinDTimm, I have added more information above.

Comment: Your code and output do not match.  Where is "Client connection accepted!" coming from?  Post _actual_ code with _actual_ results.  Also recv() returns 0 if the connection is closed, otherwise it blocks until at least 1 character is available in blocking mode.

Comment: Hi Mark Tolonen, very sharp eyed! I have updated my code as above.

Comment: @Luis: Right, I had mentioned both those error codes in my answer (note that on Windows, it's `WSAGetLastError()` to check for socket errors).  And `EINTR` is also a possibility on Linux which should be treated just like `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Sorry I had not read your answer and thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 1):

If your socket is a blocking socket, then recv function will block till you get some data. recv function will return 0 only when the other side closes the connection on most systems.

I suggest you recheck your code and execution and let us know the exact output.

Refer [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Sorry about that, had an extra sentence to add to my answer and hit edit on yours by mistake.  Now reverted, but it still logged the edit.

Comment: Not a problem at all Ben! Actually, if you feel any changes are required to my answer, please feel free to do so. : )

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `recv` only returns 0 if the remote end closes the connection (for stream sockets such as TCP) or if a packet with no payload is received (datagram sockets such as UDP).

If the socket has been set to non-blocking mode (default is blocking), and there's no data *yet*, you'd get an error code, either `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` depending on the OS.

In any case, each time `recv` returns, the new data will be stored at the beginning of the buffer.  It won't append to previously received data unless you calculate a pointer designed to store new data after the old.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what to expect of the data that you receive you can drop the first set of characters. For example if you know what will the length of the packet be or the source of the message or the header information then you can validate and ignore the first set of characters.

Comment: Thanks ckv, I'll try to do that.

Comment: Hey ckv, the first few characters happen to be null characters... Am having trouble trying to discard the first few null chars.

Comment: Ok mate, got it. Nested the recv in two while loops.